# Find Last Two Digits

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the last two digits of $33^{555}$

I have tried this: $33^{555}=3\times (10-1)^{277}\times(10+1)^{555} $. So the answer is $57$.

Is it correct?

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion from your equation?

Comment: Then your proof is correct as long as you can show $(10-1)^{277}\equiv 69$ and $(10+1)^{555}\equiv 51$.

Comment: Alternatively use $\varphi(100)=40$: $$33^{555}\equiv 33^{-5}\equiv(-3)^5\equiv -243\equiv 57 \mod 100.$$

Comment: @tkf nice! Thanks

Comment: $57$... checked by computer in $0.000014$ seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correct.

Using binomial expansion,
\begin{align}
3 \times (10-1)^{277} \times (10+1)^{555} &\equiv 3 \times (277(10) - 1) \times ( 5550 + 1) \pmod{100} \\
&\equiv 3 \cdot (70 - 1) \cdot (50+1) \pmod{100}\\
&\equiv 3 \cdot (70-50-1) \pmod{100}\\
&\equiv 3 \cdot (20-1) \pmod{100} \\
&\equiv 60-3\pmod{100}\\
&\equiv 57 \pmod{100}
\end{align}